# Change Cell Reference Within a Repetition

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to transpose data on a single row into a table. What I'm doing is taking a base inventory item and creating 6 more items from it. For example, my base inventory item is a ball, and I want to create 6 different balls from that of various colours (blue ball, black ball, and so forth). To do so, I've used the REPT function to repeat a process 6 times to create my list of inventory items.

```
=transpose(split(rept(C4&""&F4&""&";",6),";"))
```

C4 contains my base inventory item code (ie: ball) while F4 contains the subcode (ie: -blue). The formula combines these values in "ball-blue" etc.

This works just fine. The problem I'm running into is that I want to change the F4 cell reference each time it repeats. I want to shift it to the right so that I can pick up the rest of subcodes into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:J4<>""; C4&"-"&F4:J4; )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. How would I make this work if I needed to skip columns? Let's say every other column needs to be skipped because it contains other data that doesn't need to be combined. Thanks.

Comment: try: `=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:J4<>"", C4&"-"&F4:J4, )), MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(F4:J4)))+1, 2)=0)` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/coTSz.png